# Expo not read googleMobileAdsAppId in App.json

Tags: react-native, expo

i run `expo build:android` but i am go to my build or install apk in my phone the app is close and show this error: **Invalid application ID**

My app.json

[image]

But honestly I've been broken my brain for hours on this and it doesn't make sense my appId is already in app.json but when I try to build my manifest doesn't show up...

[image]

My workflow details

[image]

Ty for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that some googleServices.json was interfering with the build of the app!